# Boolean startup params in Ansible

Tags: ansible

actually I'm working on a role which should be able to prepare app servers for future steps. Some of that points are:

- install java on appserver
- install perl on appserver
- doing os update
- doing reboot ...

In case of that to decide when the role should so the tasks I wanna implement boolean parameters which I can change by using the role over a playbook.

I will go deeper specially for installing java (I think the steps for the other tools are quietly the same). 
In my main.yml in tasks folder I include first of al a sub task file called "check-startup-params.yml"

```
  - include: check-startup-params.yml
```

The content of check-startup-params.yml is quiet less => Ansible should look for the variable "javainstall" and set it to "false" if it is undefined or has another value as "true"

```
  - name: Set Parameter for Java install to false when unset or value is wrong
    set_fact:
      javainstall: false
    when: javainstall is undefined javainstall | bool != true
```

Later in the main.yml task file I'm including the installationtasks for java depending on "javainstall is true".

```
  - include: install-java.yml
    when: javainstall
```

When I use the role over a playbook like this:

```sh
ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/playbooks/prepare-app-deploy.yml -i /etc/ansible/hosts --ask-vault-pass -e @/etc/ansible/vaults/vault.yml -e host=myhosts
```

so without setting javainstall Ansible will set the value to false and skipps the tasks to install java. Same is working, when I set javainstall to true like this:

```sh
ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/playbooks/prepare-app-deploy.yml -i /etc/ansible/hosts --ask-vault-pass -e @/etc/ansible/vaults/vault.yml -e host=myhosts -e javainstall=true
```

But now I'm trying to set javainstall directly to false:

```sh
ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/playbooks/prepare-app-deploy.yml -i /etc/ansible/hosts --ask-vault-pass -e @/etc/ansible/vaults/vault.yml -e host=myhosts -e javainstall=false
```

Ansible now interprets the variable as "setted" and so as "boolean => true" and installs java. But I don't want it.

So I think I misunderstand here how Ansible is looking for and using boolean vars.

I've also tried to try it with Jinja format like this:

```sh
ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/playbooks/prepare-app-deploy.yml -i /etc/ansible/hosts --ask-vault-pass -e @/etc/ansible/vaults/vault.yml -e host=myhosts -e "{'javainstall':false}"
```

Here ansible throws me this error:

```
fatal: [fgi_banksystem_ha2_lx1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'javainstall is undefined javainstall | bool != true' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if javainstall is undefined javainstall | bool != true %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): test_undefined() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/roles/prepare-app-deploy/tasks/check-startup-params.yml': line 2, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n  - name: Set Parameter for Java install to false when unset or value is wrong\n    ^ here\n"}
```

In case of that I want to design a Jenkins job later on which should set the "true or false" by checking a checkox or not I need a way how I can send a boolean var to Ansible by staring over a playbook.

But how?

Thanks and regards,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this probably what you're looking for?

```
- name: Set Parameter for Java install to false when unset or value is wrong
    set_fact:
      javainstall: false
    when: javainstall|default(false)|bool != true
```

Note. `javainstall: indefinite` behave like `false`. The tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    javainstall: indefinite
- debug:
    msg: indefinite is false
  when: not javainstall|bool
```

give

```
"msg": "indefinite is false"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit ambiguity in a way Ansible handles types. The best way I found insofar is to use Jinja2 to be sure of types.

Example:

```
ansible-playbook ... -e 'javainstall={{ True }}'  #or False
```

By this way you can be sure that `javainstall` is boolean. Another thing to mind, that 'is defined' is really bad pattern, it's better to use default values instead:

```
when: javainstall|d(False)
```

The `d` filter is shorthand for `default`. Last thing to notice, is that `bool` is not a normal python `bool()` function. It's a very different code to convert strings like 'off', 'on', 'yes', 'no', etc into boolean values.